# In Sql Service Broker, is it possible to create a dialog with specific conversation_handle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, service-broker

I'm using Service Broker as a messaging queue for a job engine. When the jobs are created they are given a Guid that is used by the system to track the progress of a job. Given that, would it be possible to create a dialog in Service Broker that uses a given Guid instead of creating it's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, conversation_handles are created for you, you cannot specify them.

Answer (score 1):

You can specifiy a `RELATED_CONVERSATION_GROUP` (a GUID) when you do `BEGIN DIALOG`.  A conversation group is just made up and tracked by your application, and you can receive messages for that conversation group or see what conversation group a received message belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

As @RBarryYoung says, no, you cannot.

Could you turn the question on it's head? Could you delay needing a job Guid until you start a dialog, and then use the returned conversation handle as the job Guid?

Comment: I possibly can, might not make sense for all jobs, and I considered that route, but it would have been much easier if I could have just specified my own id